Getting error when selecting autofill value in prime react input number component
I am getting an error when i try to select a autofill value
I am using prime react inputnumber component
enter image description here
when i debug ,there is no value in event.Even if to turn off autocomplete ,there is no option for that in input number
How to solve this?

Passthrough attributes, autocomplete can be used like this
<InputNumber  value={value1} onValueChange={(e) => setValue1(e.value)} pt={{ input: { root: { autocomplete: 'off' } } }} />

